The Accuracy of Kriging Interpolation
I am attempting to interpolate the normal strain results in the wall type structure (dimensions:800x500 mm) while having approximately 150 scattered known points in the whole element (find picture for the Sensor Layout).
I used universal kriging with the Pykrige toolkit, but the lowest error margin I achieved, when compared to FEM results, was 37%, which seems very high. This was with a Gaussian variogram. I also tried creating a custom variogram model, but the results seemed incorrect with an effective range of 839.42, sill and nugget effect both 0, and an even higher error margin.
Am I creating the variogram model incorrectly? Is Kriging suitable for this case, or should I use simpler interpolation methods? Should I add anything else to the interpolation like trend model, use zonal Kriging (as I have three distinct zones for high, medium and low strains), or implement drift_term?
Here is my Python code:
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pykrige.uk import UniversalKriging
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import skgstat as skg

# Load the known strain data and x, y locations from the Excel file using pandas
excel_file = 'Sensor-Results(Exx).xlsx'
data = pd.read_excel(excel_file)

# Extract x, y, and strain values from the DataFrame by using their names on top of the columns
x_known = data['X'].values
y_known = data['Y'].values
strain_known = data['Exx'].values

# Define the grid dimensions
grid_width = 800  # in mm
grid_height = 500  # in mm

# Define the grid division
width1 = 37.5  # in mm
width2 = 50  # in mm
width3 = 282.5  # in mm
width4 = 60  # in mm

# Generate points using the provided divisions (For creating the identical mesh to FEM model)
x1 = np.linspace(0, width1, 1)  # Grid on 0 location
x2 = np.linspace(width1, width1 + width2, 1)  # Grid on 37.5 location
x3 = np.linspace(width1 + width2, 370, 8)  # Grid on 127.857 to 370
x4 = np.linspace(400, width1 + width2 + width3 + width4, 2)
x5 = np.linspace(width1 + width2 + width3 + width4 + width3 / 7, width1 + width2 + width3 * 2 + width4, 7)
x6 = np.linspace(width1 + width2 * 2 + width3 * 2 + width4, grid_width, 2)

# Combine all x points
x_grid = np.unique(np.concatenate((x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6)))
y_grid = np.linspace(0, grid_height, 14)

# Create a meshgrid of the grid points
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x_grid, y_grid)

# Flatten the meshgrid arrays
x_flat = X.flatten()
y_flat = Y.flatten()

# Create empirical variogram
coords = np.vstack((x_known, y_known)).T
strain_known = strain_known.flatten()
V = skg.Variogram(coords, strain_known, n_lags=15, normalize=True, model='gaussian', estimator='dowd')
fig = V.plot(show=False)
plt.show()
print(V)

# Extract variogram parameters
variogram_model_parameters = V.parameters
variogram_model = 'gaussian'
print("Variogram Model Parameters:", variogram_model_parameters)

# Perform Universal Kriging interpolation for the full grid with linear drift
uk = UniversalKriging(
    x_known, y_known, strain_known,
    variogram_model=variogram_model,
    variogram_parameters=variogram_model_parameters,
    drift_terms=['regional_linear']
)
strain_interpolated, _ = uk.execute('grid', x_grid, y_grid)

# Replace the interpolated values at known data points with the actual known values
for x, y, strain in zip(x_known, y_known, strain_known):
    xi = np.abs(x_grid - x).argmin()
    yi = np.abs(y_grid - y).argmin()
    strain_interpolated[yi, xi] = strain

# Create a DataFrame with all grid points and interpolated strain values
interpolated_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'X': x_flat,
    'Y': y_flat,
    'Strain': strain_interpolated.flatten()
})

# Sort the DataFrame to achieve the desired zigzag order
interpolated_sorted = pd.DataFrame(columns=['X', 'Y', 'Strain'])

for x_val in x_grid:
    temp_df = interpolated_df[interpolated_df['X'] == x_val]
    idx = np.where(x_grid == x_val)[0][0]
    if idx % 2 == 0:  # Even index
        interpolated_sorted = pd.concat([interpolated_sorted, temp_df])
    else:  # Odd index
        interpolated_sorted = pd.concat([interpolated_sorted, temp_df.iloc[::-1]])

# Save the interpolated data
interpolated_sorted.to_csv('24_06_21_Kriging-Variogram(Exx).txt', sep='\t', index=False, header=True)

# Plot the heat map
strain_grid = strain_interpolated.reshape(X.shape)
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
plt.contourf(X, Y, strain_grid, cmap='rainbow')
plt.colorbar()

# Scatter plot with connecting lines
plt.scatter(x_known, y_known, color='black', s=10)
plt.plot(x_known, y_known, color='red', linewidth=1, linestyle='-')

plt.xlabel('X (mm)')
plt.ylabel('Y (mm)')
plt.title('Strain Heatmap Exx')
plt.show()

The data that I am analyzing is randomly taken from the FEM model that I have created. The contour plot shows the distinct zones of high low and medium strain results, gradually changing in y direction.
From the default UK, the toolkit somehow gives me different parameters from variogram analysis.
Sill: 4.94245937e-06
Range: 1.85944481e+02
Nugget: 1.04982139e-06
These results are quite different when I create a custom variogram for example for Gaussian Variogram the effective range, sill, nugget are printed as follows:
[839.4157043511434, 1.234774627684911e-05, 0]
What could be the reason of such difference in custom and default variogram results?

the first question to answer: does normal strain respect a spatial variance model described by a gaussian variogram?

For Finite Element Analysis mainly the linear interpolation is used to handle the space in between close known points. The strain in my case has a gradual change in its values across the structure and there is no randomness (as I have ideal environment). @imbr is there a way to find exactly if the specific variogram works for my case? As mentioned from my plotting the variance does not look promising as sill equals to 0.

you need to analyse your sample data with a sample variogram and check how your data variance behaves like here. It also might be the case that it behaves like one model (like gaussian) for one direction (like north-south) and in another direction another model (like a spherical) works better. You need to make those sample variograms and check.

Looking at your data it seens there are two trends of spatial variance one -y -> y+ and other -x -> x+ but need to confirm on the sample variogram. That one you provided is in which direction or is it omnidirectional?

welll just took a look at the pykrige it seens it doesn't support anything except omnidirectional variogram models.

@imbr Thanks for the reply. I have edited the post.
